# Degrees, as numbers or units in SI system

Tags: siunitx, units

When typesetting degrees the correct way is to make the degrees symbol part of the number (without the space between the degree symbol and the number.)

Technically in the SI system then degrees C or degrees F should be typeset with a space between the degrees symbol and the unit.

The `\SI{23}{\celsius}` does not do this correctly.

Is this a bug or a feature?

(kindly provide your reference source)

Comment: It's a feature, `siunitx` handles both temperatures and angles correctly. In the SI system, there has to be a space between the number and the degree symbol and no space between the degree symbol and the `C` when typesetting temperatures. See [section 5.3.3 of the official SI brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter5/5-3-2.html).

Comment: Fahrenheit and Rankine are not part of the SI system. The degree symbol in `°C` makes it possible to tell the derived unit for Celsius temperature apart from the base unit coulomb (`C`). It is therefore part of the unit symbol.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me. It adds the degrees symbol where it should be. Please post as answer.

Comment: The brochure section @Jake has linked to is now located at: http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3-3.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a feature, `siunitx` handles both temperatures and angles correctly. In the SI system, there has to be a space between the number and the degree symbol and no space between the degree symbol and the `C` when typesetting temperatures. See [section 5.3.3 of the official SI brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3-3.html).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can with this code:

```
\SI{78,4}{\degreeCelsius}
```

Comment: Isn't command `\SI` deprecated?

Comment: Didn't know that, what should I use instead?

Comment: See the note about `\SI` in the manual of `siunitx` v3.x (and the documentation of the new commands in the same manual).

Comment: This is not actually an answer to the question.